Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file for loop range
I have the following code:
def openFile():
filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                                      title="Please select a file",
                                      filetypes = (('Excel files', '*.xlsx'),
                                                  ('Excel macro files', '*.xlsm'))
                                      )
                                                                    
    file = open(filepath, 'r')
    wb = load_workbook(filepath, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
    ws=wb.active
    fileonly = filepath.split('/')[-1]
    filewithoutextension = fileonly.split('-')[0]
    fileextension = fileonly.split('.')[-1]

    y = pyautogui.prompt(text='Please specify the number of file duplicates', title='Number of files', default='2')

    file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

    print(y)

    for x in range(2, (int(y))+1):
         newname = "%03d" % x
         dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"COLLECTION,INTER PROJECT COLLECTION,INTER PROJECT TRANSFER,TRANSFER"', allow_blank=False)
         dv.error = 'Please select entry from the list!'
         c1 = ws["D4"]
         c1.value = "COLLECTION"
         dv.add(c1)
         ws.add_data_validation(dv)
         save_path = Path(file_path) / f"{filewithoutextension}- {newname}.{fileextension}"
         wb.save(save_path)
         print (filewithoutextension+'- '+newname+'.'+fileextension)
         wb.close()


rootwindow = tk.Tk()
rootwindow.geometry("500x100")
rootwindow.title("Excel file duplicator")
font.families()
windowfont=tk.font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
windowfont.config(
    family="Segoe Script",
    size=24,
    weight=font.BOLD)

button = tk.Button(rootwindow, text='Open Excel 
document',command=openFile, fg='black', bg='yellow')
button.pack()
rootwindow.mainloop()

which throws the following error:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
Tried to use the file.close() and other solutions included in the code, which are listed here, but they didn't work.
Python error : Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
ValueError : I/O operation on closed file
How could I apply them to the situation, where instead of file I have a loop between a multitude of files?
UPDATE:
Previously I had a problem with saving images with the files duplicated by openpyxl.
By using the following solution:
Images dissapear in excel documents when copying them with python
I have installed the Pillow library. The error has appeared since the installation.

Fix the code indentation first.

where exactly? I have no error regarding indentation at all

I think that from second line to the end of  the posted code should be indented.

In my original code it's intended.

We don't have your original code, we have only the posted code.

I don't understand why the with file block is necessary because file is not used inside the block.

I just used the solution, I don't know honestly what should be applied here.

Now you can see the whole code

The indentation in the posted code is still broken. We could guess what you really mean, and maybe be correct, but it's much easier for you to just fix it here than for every reader to have to guess what you meant.

Ok now indentation should be correct

wb.close() inside the for loop is pretty sus

even if outside, it doesn't worfk

Please post the full error traceback to indicate where the error is actually occurring.

file = open(filepath, 'r') is useless because as said in my past comment, file is not used in the posted code.  Also after adding proper import statements and fixing indentation issue, your code works fine.

Your code runs for me and basically achieves what you presumably are attempting to achieve with a couple of small issues.
I have gone through the code to highlight the issues that I see.
These are listed below, none of them are major or would cause runtime errors.

The line file = open(filepath, 'r') is extraneous, it makes no sense to include it. There is no requirement to open a handle on the Excel file, Openpyxl doesn't need it, and you dont use it anywhere in the code anyway.
Your selecting either an Excel file, XLSX or Excel macro file XLSM which is loaded by Openpyxl with keep_vba=True and later save copies of using the original extension.
This means an XLSX files can be opened with keep_vba=True and saved with an '.xlsx' extension. This will result in a mismatched file that Excel cannot open. When using keep_vba=True, the workbook is now an Excel macro workbook and must use the extension '.xlsm' to be properly recognised by Excel.
The files are OK as saved but Excel would only be able to open them after the extension is changed.
If you dont want the XLSX files to be copied as XLSM files then don't open files with '.xlsx' extension with 'keep_vba' set to True. Get the file extension first then set 'keep_vba' True or False depending on this when executing the 'load_workbook' line.
The line to get the file Excel file name without the extension is wrong filewithoutextension = fileonly.split('-')[0] should be filewithoutextension = fileonly.split('.')[0]. The delimiter is right in the next line to get the Excel file extension.
The 'Number of files' dialogue box is 'Please specify the number of file duplicates' which suggest it asking for how many copies of the selected file to make. However the range you use to create the copies is one less than this.
You start your range with value 2 but only add 1 to the input value used as the max value in the range. Therefore if the user selects the default value of '2' the range is range(2, 3) and therefore the loop will iterate once only with 'x' equal to 2.
Presume you want to iterate 2 times so the range should be range(2, (int(y)) + 2) so for our example it is range(2, 4) and x has values 2 and 3.

Update
Sample code
Changed the function 'openFile'. This includes fixing the points listed above. 

I have started the 'new files' count from 1 rather than 2. If you prefer to keep the first file starting with 002 then set the range to; 
for x in range(2, (int(y)) + 2):
The workbook is opened, saved and closed in the file copy loop so would prevent issues with PIL closing the image files between copies.

...

def openFile():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Please select a file",
        filetypes=(('Excel files', '*.xlsx'),
                   ('Excel macro files', '*.xlsm'))
    )

    print(filepath)
    fileonly = filepath.split('/')[-1]
    filewithoutextension = fileonly.split('.')[0]
    fileextension = fileonly.split('.')[-1]

    y = pyautogui.prompt(text='Please specify the number of file duplicates', title='Number of files', default='2')

    file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

    print(y)
    for x in range(1, (int(y)) + 1):
        k_vba = False
        if fileextension == 'xlsm':
            k_vba = True
        wb = load_workbook(filepath, read_only=False, keep_vba=k_vba)
        ws = wb.active

        newname = "%03d" % x

        dv = DataValidation(type="list",
                            formula1='"COLLECTION,INTER PROJECT COLLECTION,INTER PROJECT TRANSFER,TRANSFER"',
                            allow_blank=False)
        dv.error = 'Please select entry from the list!'
        c1 = ws["D4"]
        c1.value = "COLLECTION"
        dv.add(c1)
        ws.add_data_validation(dv)
        save_path = Path(file_path) / f"{filewithoutextension}- {newname}.{fileextension}"
        wb.save(save_path)
        print(filewithoutextension + '- ' + newname + '.' + fileextension)
        wb.close()


Still didn't help. After uninstalling Pillow library everything works well, but without pictures

I have currently the command with open (filepath, 'r') as f:

I dont know why you want to open the file separately, What is the reason for having open (filepath, 'r') as f: ?

I am just looking for a solution, which allow me to avoid this error. I don't know which one is correct

The changed function I have put in the answer above should prevent the error occurring. Have you tried it?

Yes, I tried your new solution and it works! Thank you. Now it;s the time for me to investigate what was wrong and where.
